# How to get a list of sub-folders and their files, ordered by folder-names

Tags: command-line, directory, dos

Can I use `dir` command-line to get a list of sub-folders and their files, ordered by folder-names, and not just file-names ?

using

> dir /s/b/o:gn > f.txt

I first get all sub-folders and only then all sub files, e.g.:

```
 d:\root0\root1\folderA
 d:\root0\root1\folderB
 d:\root0\root1\file00.txt
 d:\root0\root1\file01.txt
 d:\root0\root1\folderA\fileA00.txt
 d:\root0\root1\folderA\fileA01.txt
 d:\root0\root1\folderB\fileB00.txt
 d:\root0\root1\folderB\fileB01.txt
```

But I want to get -

```
d:\root0\root1\file00.txt
d:\root0\root1\file01.txt
d:\root0\root1\folderA
d:\root0\root1\folderA\fileA00.txt
d:\root0\root1\folderA\fileA01.txt
d:\root0\root1\folderB
d:\root0\root1\folderB\fileB00.txt
d:\root0\root1\folderB\fileB01.txt
```

["file00.txt" and "file01.txt" can also be at the end of the list]

Thanks,

Atara

Answer (score 95, accepted):

How about using `sort`?

```
dir /b /s | sort
```

Here's an example I tested with:

---

`dir /s /b /o:gn`

```
d:\root0
d:\root0\root1
d:\root0\root1\folderA
d:\root0\root1\folderB
d:\root0\root1\file00.txt
d:\root0\root1\file01.txt
d:\root0\root1\folderA\fileA00.txt
d:\root0\root1\folderA\fileA01.txt
d:\root0\root1\folderB\fileB00.txt
d:\root0\root1\folderB\fileB01.txt
```

---

`dir /s /b | sort`

```
d:\root0
d:\root0\root1
d:\root0\root1\file00.txt
d:\root0\root1\file01.txt
d:\root0\root1\folderA
d:\root0\root1\folderA\fileA00.txt
d:\root0\root1\folderA\fileA01.txt
d:\root0\root1\folderB
d:\root0\root1\folderB\fileB00.txt
d:\root0\root1\folderB\fileB01.txt
```

---

To just get directories, use the `/A:D` parameter:

```
dir /a:d /s /b | sort
```

Comment: What if I only want folder names?

Comment: Would you be so kind and update your answer how to get only files and not folders?

Comment: @HemusSan Only listing files would be this: `dir /a:-d /s /b | sort`

Answer (score 10):

Hej man, why are you using this ?

> dir /s/b/o:gn > f.txt **(wrong one)**

Don't you know what is that 'g' in '/o' ??

Check this out: http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm or dir /? for dir help

You should be using this instead:

> dir /s/b/o:n > f.txt **(right one)**

Comment: Not sure why the upvotes - this is clearly and testably WRONG. http://pastebin.com/qCUu4AHq

Answer (score 6):

`dir /b /a-d /s *.*` will fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Command to put list of all files and folders into a text file is as below:

Eg: dir /b /s | sort > ListOfFilesFolders.txt

Answer (score 1):

In command prompt go to the main directory you want the list for ... and type the command tree /f

Answer (score 1):

Best way i found if you want to use Powershell:

```
Get-childitem -path "C:\your\path\here\" -recurse -name | out-file C:\your\path\to\textfile\here\files.txt
```

Then you will get the filenames inside the folder and subfolders written in a textfile.

Answer (score 0):

### create a vbs file and copy all code below.  Change directory location to wherever you want.

```
Dim fso
Dim ObjOutFile

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile("OutputFiles.csv")

ObjOutFile.WriteLine("Type,File Name,File Path")

GetFiles("YOUR LOCATION")

ObjOutFile.Close

WScript.Echo("Completed")

Function GetFiles(FolderName)
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim ObjFolder
    Dim ObjSubFolders
    Dim ObjSubFolder
    Dim ObjFiles
    Dim ObjFile

    Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderName)
    Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

    For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine("File," & ObjFile.Name & "," & ObjFile.Path)
    Next

    Set ObjSubFolders = ObjFolder.SubFolders

    For Each ObjFolder In ObjSubFolders

        ObjOutFile.WriteLine("Folder," & ObjFolder.Name & "," & ObjFolder.Path)


        GetFiles(ObjFolder.Path)
    Next

End Function
```

Save the code as vbs and run it. you will get a list in that directory