# Command to list all files in a folder as well as sub-folders in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, command, dir

I tried searching for a command that could list all the file in a directory as well as subfolders using a command prompt command.
I have read the help for "dir" command but coudn't find what I was looking for.
Please help me what command could get this.

Comment: The below post gives the solution for your scenario.

[SubDirectory Files Listing command][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447503/how-to-get-a-list-of-sub-folders-and-their-files-ordered-by-folder-names

Comment: `dir /s` does the job.

Comment: If you are in europe you may want to do a `chcp 1252` before any of the below solutions to get our special characters right in windows..

Answer (score 435, accepted):

The below post gives the solution for your scenario.

```
dir /s /b /o:gn
```

---

**/S** Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.

**/B** Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).

**/O** List by files in sorted order.

Then in **:gn**, *g* sorts by folders and then files, and *n* puts those files in alphabetical order.

Comment: A description of the switches used would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: This outputs the path + filename not just the filename. This doesn't work. When recursive /s is added, DIR will always output the full paths in outputs. So a FOR script would likely be needed to recursively find all filenames inside a directory tree and output them in alphabetical order in a text file.

Comment: This is a great option. However, it sadly doesn't seem to work in PowerShell, which means I seem to be unable to use this command on a UNC path.

Comment: For PowerShell, try `dir -s` instead of the `/s` format for flags.

Comment: Great answer. In addition to this, because of how difficult it is to do things like copy specific parts of text from a vanilla command prompt, it can be good to append `>list.txt` to make it output to a file to be more easily used. So the command would be:

`dir /s /b /o:gn >list.txt`

Answer (score 179):

If you want to list folders and files like graphical directory tree, you should use [tree command](https://jpsoft.com/help/tree.htm).

```
tree /f
```

There are various options for display format or ordering.

Check example output.

[image]

Answering late. Hope it help someone.

Comment: Works fine inside of Windows 10 installing window!

Comment: How to print this to file? I tried >f.txt but not print exact i see

Comment: I know the OP asked for a command, but I'm wondering if you know of a GUI-style way of getting the same tree-like display of directories and files?

Comment: To answer my own comment, you can use WinDirStat. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37169035/253938

Comment: @Ajith you need to write the command properly.
Example:
cd C:\Users\username\Desktop
tree /F #Shows the tree only

tree /F>C:\Users\username\Desktop\tree.doc #Saves the tree to tree.doc file

Comment: use tree /a /f > output.doc 
.. to generate the tree as a file

Answer (score 84):

An addition to the answer: when you do not want to list the folders, only the files in the subfolders, use **/A-D** switch like this:

```
dir ..\myfolder /b /s /A-D /o:gn>list.txt
```

Comment: This solution worked great with the added bonus of exporting the list to a .txt file.

Comment: Wow, great solution. You literally saved me 25 minutes... to create folders and copy files manually

Comment: great answer >>>

Comment: Found this way to get the relative path (it uses `powershell`, though)
`powershell.exe "Get-ChildItem -Recurse . | Resolve-Path -Relative"`
[Courtesy](https://superuser.com/questions/1029558/list-files-in-a-subdirectory-and-get-relative-paths-only-with-windows-command-li)

Answer (score 9):

If you simply need to get the basic snapshot of the files + folders. Follow these baby steps:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type `cmd`
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type `dir -s`
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Without any arguments, `dir` only gives information about the files and directories in the current folder, but the OP wants the return to include files in subfolders as well.

Comment: @Vyren Thanks a lot for highlighting this! Can you please [suggest an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44676699/edit)? I am more than happy for improvements :)

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to the above commands that is a little more bulletproof.

It can list all files irrespective of permissions or path length.

```
robocopy "C:\YourFolderPath" "C:\NULL" /E /L /NJH /NJS /FP /NS /NC /B /XJ
```

I have a slight issue with the use of C:\NULL which I have written about in my blog

https://theitronin.com/bulletproofdirectorylisting/

But nevertheless it's the most robust command I know.

Answer (score 5):

The below post gives the solution for your scenario.

```
**dir /s /b /o:gn**
```

**/S** Displays files in specified directories and all subdirectories.

**/B** Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).

**/O** List by files in sorted order.

**:gn**, g sorts by folders and then files, and n puts those files in alphabetical order.

**Just for all files except long path, write the following command:**

```
**dir /b /o:gn**
```

**For Tree:**
write in your cmd

**`tree /f`**