# How to maintain source folder structure in JFrog Artifactory during upload?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have following folder structure on local machine

```
c:\git
      \repo
         \myproject
             \build
                \assets
                    \html
                    \js
                    \css
```

I am using the following command to upload artifacts to Artifactory

```
jf rt u "c:\git\repo\myproject\build\*" my-jfrog-repo-generic-local/2023/ --sync-deletes="my-jfrog-repo-generic-local/2023/"
```

This collect all files located under the `build` directory (including sub-directories), and upload them to the `my-jfrog-repo-generic-local` repository, under the `2023`folder, while maintaining the complete original path of artifacts.
So after the upload in Artifactory repository the hierarchy is

```
  `my-jfrog-repo-generic-local`
     2023
       C:
         git
           repo
             myproject
                build
                   \html
                   \js
                   \css
```

instead, I want to keep folder structure of only source folder. (Exclude source's parent folder). So in this case the target folder structure should be

```
  `my-jfrog-repo-generic-local`
     2023
        build
          \html
          \js
          \css
```

How can we do this using the JFrog CLI?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, move to the path where the folder to push is located and add the parameter `--flat=false`. It should still be a default parameter.

Some useful link:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF4X/Using+File+Specs

[How to upload complete folder structure to Artifactory repo to a new folder and keep he folder name as it is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432227/how-to-upload-complete-folder-structure-to-artifactory-repo-to-a-new-folder-and#58436393)

https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-upload-a-folder-with-its-content-to-artifactory/